# onchange event on dynamically event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

I am creating a input type file and the code is like this

```
var ele=document.createElement("INPUT");
            ele.type="file";
            ele.id="ele"+i;
            $("#media").append("<br>");
            $("#media").append("<br>");
            $('#media').append(ele);
            $('#ele'+i).on('change',change());
function change()
{
     alert("hello");
}
```

the problem is that the hello gets alerted when the element is created , why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are call method instead of passing handler name.

Change

```
$('#ele'+i).on('change',change());
```

To

```
$('#ele'+i).on('change',change);
```

You can delegate event to parent using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), you need to give event handler name i.e `change` instead of calling it like `change()`. You can use attribute selector with starts with wild card to bind event to elements having `ids` like `ele*`

```
$('#media').on('click', '[id^=ele]', change);
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: can i ask you another question?

Comment: the "#media" is a button , so when i use change() instead of change, it alerts hello on clicking it , why?

Comment: That calls the function change but does not bind it, it would be calling once IMO when this code is executed but the event wont fire.

Answer (score 2):

This line is incorrect:

```
        $('#ele'+i).on('change',change());
```

It should be:

```
        $('#ele'+i).on('change',change);
```

You were calling the function instead of passing the function as an argument.

But you shouldn't need to do this after you append each element. Give the new elements a class, and use event delegation:

```
$("#media").on("change", ".file", change); // Do this just once
function change()
{
     alert("hello");
}

var ele=document.createElement("INPUT");
ele.type="file";
ele.className = "file"
$("#media").append("<br>");
$("#media").append("<br>");
$('#media').append(ele);
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides what @adil mention,which is the correction to your error, you tagged the question with jquery so you could do

```
$('<input>', {
  type:'file',
  id: 'ele' + i,
  change: change
}).appendTo('#media');
```

Comment: i tried it , its great but adit actually told me where i was wrong , so i corrected his answer